# unable to set height of a table footer element in chrome

Tags: html, css

I have a plugin that adds an element to a table that acts like a footer via `display:table-row`.

Inside of that footer are more elements that act like table cells. The idea is that this footer should have 0 height (it used for calculating column widths by the plugin).

**The problem is that it has a height of 2px** in chrome (osx) and I cant figure out what style to override to make it have a height of 0.

currently its styles are: `display:table-footer-group;border-spacing:0;height:0;border-collapse:collapse;`

Here is a page that shows this behavior:

http://mkoryak.github.io/floatThead/tests/issue-127/
on that page if you click "float thead (abs=on)" you will see a slight shift of the buttons downwards (by 2px).

After that you can find the offending element by running this in console:

```
$("fthfoot")
$("fthfoot").height()
```

---

I can put this on jsfiddle if that will help this question stay open - but that site isnt going anywhere any time soon either.

Comment: for me it also changes the height in firefox. maybe its not only a problem with chrome

Comment: Have you solved this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That element has 2px height due to the default border-spacing of the table (seems to be 2px for Chrome).

this simple line of css can fix it:

```
table.sometable{border-spacing:0}
```

obviously this will change dimension of other cells too.

Comment: I see, that is too bad though. Thanks